# How many users can be on my website (home ubuntu-server) at same time

Tags: server

I want to build my own ubuntu-server at home.And I need to know the max number of user that can visit my web site at same.
 If it depend from software of from hardware (max)...  My website is not Google , but I need to know.

Comment: It is independant of the os

Comment: There's no real way to tell. In most likelihood your home network connection will be the bottleneck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your internet upload speed, and download speed, and system ram all play a role in figuring out your answer. Take a look at this link it may give you some insight: http://canihostaminecraftserver.com/